# MarkLogic - A message body writer for Java class com.marklogic.client.impl.StreamingOutputImpl was not found

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, marklogic

My REST endpoints are working well except for the ones that interact with MarkLogic API, it throws this stacktrace:

```
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: A message body writer for Java class com.marklogic.client.impl.StreamingOutputImpl, and Java type class com.marklogic.client.impl.StreamingOutputImpl, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java class com.marklogic.client.impl.StreamingOutputImpl, and Java type class com.marklogic.client.impl.StreamingOutputImpl, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl.<init>(RequestWriter.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.getRequestEntityWriter(RequestWriter.java:248)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.getHttpEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:241)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.getUriHttpRequest(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:197)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:153)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DigestChallengeFilter.handle(DigestChallengeFilter.java:34)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPDigestAuthFilter.handle(HTTPDigestAuthFilter.java:493)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.doPost(JerseyServices.java:3492)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.search(JerseyServices.java:1855)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.search(JerseyServices.java:1719)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryManagerImpl.validate(QueryManagerImpl.java:460)
    at org.cambridge.aop.ml.springdata.core.MarkLogicTemplate.queryForPage(MarkLogicTemplate.java:153)
    at org.cambridge.aop.ml.springdata.repository.support.AbstractMarkLogicRepository.search(AbstractMarkLogicRepository.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:401)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy188.search(Unknown Source)
    at org.cambridge.aop.idm.service.search.SearchServiceImpl.searchIdentities(SearchServiceImpl.java:49)
    at org.cambridge.aop.idm.api.search.SearchRestServiceImpl.searchIdentities(SearchRestServiceImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    ... 78 more
```

I'm using this marklogic java api declared as one of the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-api-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, please do note that these are all running fine if I run the application from my IDE (manual run as java application (jetty startup)), no errors. But if I run it from the jar file using the command line "java -jar ..." it throws the error. I've been trying to play around with the dependencies but to no luck.  Here's a snippet of the effective POM of my server module:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>aop-idm-security</groupId>
  <artifactId>aop-idm-security</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>client-api-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.17</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.17</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>14.0.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Appreciate if someone can point out where could I possibly gone wrong.. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to run your application as a stand-alone runnable jar or are you deploying it on Jetty?

Comment: I'm running it as a runnable uber jar from maven shade plugin. CXF dependencies is needed to create the jaxrs server and jersey is needed as well as one of the dependencies of MarkLogic java API. I've tried removing the org.glassfish.jersey.* dependencies but still no luck. Same error.

Comment: If you say it works when you do it as a Jetty startup, I would check what libraries are used in the app (WEB-INF/lib) in the Jetty deploy and compare those to what the maven shade is exporting. Maybe maven shade is including or excluding a library that should or shouldn't be there (but pay closer attention to the CXF/Jersey dependencies).

Comment: Yes it works fine when I run my Startup.java from Eclipse creating the ServletContext and eventually starting jetty server. I'm not sure if I can have a clear comparison because there's no WEB-INF/lib in my source codes, I'm just loading the context and bootstrapping the Jetty Server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thanks for John Smith's input above. I found out that the problem comes with maven shaded jar. META-INF/services aren't properly transformed so I need to add the following to resolve the issue:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

The above should be added as one of the transformers for maven-shade-plugin in POM.xml

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be causing your issue is that you're including Jersey as a dependency, but the exception comes from CXF instead (which is probably bundled with your Jetty). Jersey and CXF are both JAX-RS implementations, so they are very likely conflicting with each other. Try removing Jersey from your pom or excluding CXF from your Jetty (if you have it there).